# tf.einsum with unknown shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

My problem started when I was trying to create a list in tensorflow from  a numpy list. The best way I've found was to create a matrix with all entries in that list, according to:
 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15056/how-to-use-lists-in-tensorflow

So each row represents one element of my numpy list, there're in total `N`  elements (or tensors). In the example below, I've two lists, represented by both matrices `X1` and `X2`, all shapes of each tensor (or list) are represented in another matrix, respectively called `shapeX1` and `shapeX2`.

I reshape the first row of `X1` and `X2` (representing the first element of two lists) with the shape information in `shapeX1` and `shapeX2`, and then I compute `tf.einsum` between both as follows:

```
X1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=(N,M1))
shapeX1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(N,3))
X2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=(N,M2))
shapeX2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(N,3)) 
tensX1 = tf.reshape(X1[0,:], shape=[shapeX1[0,0],shapeX1[0,1],shapeX1[0,2]]) 
tensX2 = tf.reshape(X2[0,:], shape=[shapeX2[0,0],shapeX2[0,1]])
P = tf.einsum('ijk,jk->ik', tensX1, tensX2)
```

The dimensions of each tensor `tensX1` and `tensX2` are compatible for the calculation, regarding the expression `'ijk,jk->ik'`. However I'm getting an error with `tf.einsum` (just below):

> ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.

Probably because both variables `tensX1` and `tensX2` have unknown dimensions:

```
print tensX1
Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, ?, ?), dtype=float64)

print tensX2
Tensor("Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float64)
```

In my case, the shape of each tensor isn't the same, i.e. each row of `shapeX1` (or`shapeX2`) doesn't necessarily have the same dimensions. 
So I can't define it previously.

Please
how can I fix it? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution? (I'm having exactly the same issue)

Comment: @JuanIgnacioGil Yes, I found out a way to work around this issue. It was a long time ago and I tried several things, so I don't remember exactly what I did. I would say to try two things: One option is to compute `P` in a different way by applying `tf.reduce_sum` instead of `tf.einsum`, i.e.: 
`P=tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tensX1, tensX2[tf.newaxis,:,:]), 1)`
Another possibility is to use `set_shape()` to set the shape of both tensors before computing `tf.einsum`.

Comment: Thanks! I had found the set_shape solution and that's what I'm using. It feels a bit unnatural, but works.

Comment: I understand it. I had to use it in other things and I've the same impression.